# FTP Issue - Failed to retrieve directory listing

Tags: linux, ftp

I have successfully login into ftp @ localhost but not able to list the home directory of ftp.

Comment: Might have to do something with your network configuration (ftp data channel might be blocked for eg.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have firewall configured and have kept only port 20 and 21 opened. Change the FTP client to connect using Active or the PORT method and you will be able to connect to the FTP and retrieve the directory listing.
Or else you can try after disabling the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

try passive mode FTP session, you can enter into that mode by entering the passive command